# Buildozer -v android debug (Ubuntu 18.04 venv Python3 Kivy 1.11.1)

Tags: android, python3, kivy

Right after the beginning ...

```
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/vasco/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
[INFO]:    Found NDK revision 17.2.4988734
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /home/vasco/Py/Kivy/venv/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
[WARNING]: Missing executable: pkg-config is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Found a single valid recipe set: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mix$
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2 bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name myapp and requirements (python3, kivy)
.....
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127:
RAN: /home/vasco/Py/Kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_$
  STDOUT:
/home/vasco/Py/Kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_$
  STDERR:

# Command failed: /home/vasco/Py/Kivy/venv/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=$
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Anyone has any ideas on how to extricate oneself from this problem? A related question I saw just now is 9 months old and no one ventured a suggestion.

Thks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try installing the packages that it complains about not being installed?

Comment: Hi, John. I did install them, namely autoconf and, later, libtools. But the problem persisted. In my previous question, I learned that 18.04 Kivy repositories had problems and was advised to use a virtual environment to at least have Kivy with Python3 working normally. So Python-for-Android can wait until I change to another Ubuntu release or opt for another distro. Thks.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04 without using a virtual environment.  Rather than using the Ubuntu python3 repository, I downloaded the source from python.org and did the compile and install and installed kivy using pip.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, John, but now I am a bit confused: you mean that you downloaded Python3 itself from Python.org for compile & install?!

Comment: After looking more closely (it has been a while), I think I experimented with compiling Python, but I see that I now have the Ubuntu `python3,6` package installed. However, I did install kivy v1.11 using pip.